# Threads not synchronising propelry

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two class which extend thread, one reads from a folder the other renames a file in that folder. My issue is i ideally wanted the classes to take turns into reading however it seems as though my writer class jumps the gun every now and then and i cant see why. In my reader class below the run method is as follows. while the time is within the cut off period "script runs for an hour" do the following

```
while(cTime.before(cutOff)) 
        {

            File[] paths;
            ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
            GenericExtFilter filter = new GenericExtFilter(ext);

                paths = f.listFiles(filter);

                Arrays.sort(paths, new Comparator<File>(){
                    public int compare (File a, File b){
                        return (int) (a.lastModified() - b.lastModified());
                    }
                });

                for(int j=0;j<paths.length;j++){
                    names.add(paths[j].getName());

                }

                if(!names.isEmpty())
                if(!names.contains("jobcard.inp"))
                {
                    dObj.setToken(paths[0]);//set the token as the file that needs to be renamed
                    cTime = new Time(date1.getTime());

                }
                else{
                    try {
                        System.out.println("sleep");
                        Thread.sleep(30*1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

        }
```

In my writer class i simply rename the file passed through by the get token however every now and then within this class it seems to be notified and it runs and tries to find the file which it had already renamed "no such file exception"

```
while(cTime.before(cutOff))
    {

    d.getToken(this);

    source=path.toPath();
    try {
        Files.move(source, source.resolveSibling("jobcard.inp"));
        cTime = new Time(date1.getTime());
        Thread.sleep(30*1000);
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
```

Lastly i have a holder for both of these classes which has the sync methods

```
package reader;

import java.io.File;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class DataStore {

File path= null;
private int turn=0;

protected synchronized void setToken(File paths) {
    while(turn!=0){
        try{
            wait();
        }catch(InterruptedException ie){}
    }
    path = paths;
    turn = 1-turn;

    notify();
    return;

}
protected synchronized void getToken(InpWriter inpWriter){
    while(turn ==0){
        try{
            wait();
        }catch(InterruptedException ie){

        }

    }
    System.out.println(turn);
    inpWriter.makeFile(path);
    turn = 1-turn;

    notify();
    return;
}
```

}

Comment: Did you consider ditching the token-mechanic and instead start the writer from the reader-thread, maybe using a [FutureTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) instead of a thread? When you worry about the overhead of creating multiple threads: execute a FutureTask with a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) of size 1 will reuse the same thread and not create a new one for each task.

Comment: With a bit of research this actually sounds like a cool response thanks @Philipp currently the method i'm using takes almost half of the CPU at times